# PostgreSQL 9.6 CentOS 7 LibreTime - Job for postgresql.service failed

Tags: postgresql, centos7

I'm trying to use this with LibreTime, but for some reason it cannot start postgresql.

> ```
> systemctl start postgresql
> Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
> ```

Here's the info from `journalctl -xe`  - NOTE - I changed my actual hostname for privacy purposes:

```
journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql.service has begun starting up.
Jun 17 07:53:55 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: LOG:  could not bind IPv6
Jun 17 07:53:55 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: HINT:  Is another postmas
Jun 17 07:53:55 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: LOG:  could not bind IPv4
Jun 17 07:53:55 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: HINT:  Is another postmas
Jun 17 07:53:55 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: WARNING:  could not creat
Jun 17 07:53:55 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: FATAL:  could not create
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: pg_ctl: could not start s
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN pg_ctl[14576]: Examine the log output.
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL d
-- Subject: Unit postgresql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service ente
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
Jun 17 07:53:56 HOSTNAMEHIDDEN polkitd[470]: Unregistered Authenticatio
lines 1579-1601/1601 (END)
```

I am new to CentOS and am trying to follow this tutorial to get this thing working.  This seems to be the only point of failure.  http://libretime.org/manual/preparing-the-server/

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

-edit- here's the full code, oops:

```
systemctl status postgresql.service -l
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-06-17 08:30:43 EDT; 18s ago
  Process: 15512 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15507 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 17 08:30:42 HostnameHidden pg_ctl[15512]: LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
Jun 17 08:30:42 HostnameHidden pg_ctl[15512]: HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
Jun 17 08:30:42 HostnameHidden pg_ctl[15512]: LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
Jun 17 08:30:42 HostnameHidden pg_ctl[15512]: HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
Jun 17 08:30:42 HostnameHidden pg_ctl[15512]: WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
Jun 17 08:30:42 HostnameHidden pg_ctl[15512]: FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
Jun 17 08:30:43 HostnameHidden systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 17 08:30:43 HostnameHidden systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Jun 17 08:30:43 HostnameHidden systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 08:30:43 HostnameHidden systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
```

Comment: can you check if any other process is running on 5432? "netstat -tulpn | grep 5432"

Comment: hmm yeah looks like i got this
`netstat -tulpn | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2879/postmaster
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      2879/postmaster`  one thing i forgot to mention is i DID have postgresql 10 on here originally, i did `yum remove postgresql` or whatever to get it off.  is it possible part of it's still on there?  thanks again

Comment: Kill the process 2879. kill -9 <process id> and try starting the postgres service

Comment: ran that, tried `systemctl start postgresql` but it's doing the same thing looks like

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is a terrible "answer," but I "fixed" it by pulling off version 9.6 and putting on version 9.3.

Thanks again.